# BufferedReader is initialised but readLine returns null?

Tags: java, file, inputstream, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

I have a class `measurementFile` its constructor is posted below. and in the class `File_IO_03` which has the `main` method, i instantiate an object of the afrementioned class but when I try to `readLine` using `mf.getbR.readLine` te console displays null.

To note: `mf` is te object of the formerly mentioned class and `getbR()` is a method in that class that should return a `bufferedReader object` initialised.

Below is my attempt to read a line frm a file using `bufferedReader`

***Code***:

```
**File_IO_03**:

    File f = new File(path);
    MeasurementFile mf = new MeasurementFile(f, MeasurementFile.ENCODING_ISO_8859_1);

    if ( (mf.getiS() == null) || (mf.getbR() == null) ) {
        System.out.println("either iS or bR is null");
    }else {
        System.out.println("both iS or bR are initialised"); // successful
        System.out.println("path: " + mf.getFile().getAbsolutePath());// displayed
        System.out.println("" + mf.getbR().readLine()); // this returns null
        System.out.println("total lines in the file: " + mf.getTotalLines());// successful
        readLines(mf, 4);
        //readLines(mf, 6);
        //continueReading(mf);
    }

    private static void readLines(MeasurementFile mf, int lines) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    /*InputStream is = new FileInputStream(mf.getFile());
    mf.setiS(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mf.getiS()));
    mf.setbR(br);*/

    String line;
    int linecounter = 0;

    while ((line = mf.getbR().readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("current line read: " + line);
        if (++linecounter == lines) {
            mf.getbR().mark(0);
            System.out.println("mark set at linecounter: " + linecounter + "lines: " + lines);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**MeasurementFile Class_ Constructor**:

```
    public MeasurementFile(File file, Charset encoding) throws IOException {
    this.setFile(file);

    //if (this.myFile.setReadOnly()) 
    this.getFile().setReadable(true);
    this.getFile().setWritable(true);

    if (this.getiS() == null) {
        this.iS = new FileInputStream(this.getFile());
        this.setiS(this.iS);
    }
    if (this.getbR() == null) {
        this.bR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getiS()));
        this.setbR(this.bR);
    }

    this.totalLines = countTotalLines();

    if (this.getTotalLines() > 0) {
        this.fileToHash();
        this.splitFileIntoPages();
    }else 
        System.out.println("@MeasurementFile(): The file is empty can not create more data");
}
```

Comment: since your bufferedReader is initialized and .readLine() method returns NULL, then, it is either the file is empty or the buferedReader.readLine() reached the end of file and there are no more lines to display

Answer (score 0):

if your file is empty, it will return null, because the file is empty.
You can use the File.isEmpty() or the BufferedReader.isEmpty() methods to work out if the file is empty. For example,

```
File f= new File("Foo.txt");
if (f.isEmpty){
    continue;
}
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
String line = reader.readLine();
```

What I think you should do as well is maybe check if reader.readLine().length < 0. For example:

```
String line = reader.readLine();
if(line.length < 0){
    // File is empty
    continue;
}else{
    // File is not empty
}
```

This will make sure your file contains something when you write it.